# How to validate that at least one textbox was filled in (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2003

I have 4 textboxes, and I am trying to validate that at least one of the textboxes is filled before they hit search to check their search criteria.

**My Problem:** My code is working, but when I want to continue with one filled field, it still shows the messageBox.

```
If txtMember.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value!")
        ElseIf txtReference.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value!")
        ElseIf txtName.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value!")
        ElseIf txtCode.TextLength = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value!")
        Else
            SearchClick()
        End If
```

How  do I fix this? Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me that `txtCode.TextLength` would be a number, e.g. 0, rather than a string, e.g. "".

Comment: That one was a mistake. TextLength shouldn't be there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is something like below what you want? 
So if every text box is blank you want a message box to appear otherwise if one of the text boxes is filled in then do `SearchClick` [How to use If Else](http://vb.net-informations.com/programflow/vb.net_if_else_endif.htm). Learning to step through the code, might have helped you realise what was happening in your code.

```
If txtMember.Text = "" AndAlso txtReference.Text = "" AndAlso txtName.Text = "" AndAlso  txtCode.TextLength = "" Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value!")
Else
    SearchClick()
End If
```

Comment: You might find this interesting: [What is the difference between And and AndAlso in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/302047/1115360)

Comment: @AndrewMorton I know the difference, I kind of wrote this in a hurry but it would be useful for OP to know certainly. Updated answer.

Comment: I see you changed to "AndAlso". "And" did the trick for me as well. Is there a difference to these two, or are they the same?

Comment: @Ridge if you follow the link Andrew Morton, it will explain it better in more detail. But in short, `AndAlso` is a short-circuit method. `And` will check all the statements whereas `AndAlso` will stop once once it knows one of the conditions is false. So if `txtRefence` isn't empty for example it will stop checking the rest because it knows the condition is false so it saves time when doing a lot of checks.

Comment: This fails if a space is entered... need to check this.

Comment: `txtMember.Text.Trim() = ""` would work to remove spaces

Comment: use string.empty instead of "".  this causes the compiler to create an empy string just to do the compare whereas string.empty is a constant and will save some clock cycles.

Comment: That would make sense as well. Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 2):

The `All` and `Any` extension methods are useful in such cases, e.g.

```
If {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3}.Any(Function(tb) tb.TextLength > 0) Then
    'At least one TextBox has some text in it.
```

Comment: I think this creates more overhead and not easily readable than just using an if/elseif.  First create an array...  then create the enumerable.., then search the elements... I would stick to the if-elseif

Comment: What does "create the enumerable" mean? If you're talking about the `Enumerable` class then an instance is not created because extension methods are static. If you mean the object that is enumerated then the array IS that object, i.e. a `TextBox` array implements `IEnumerable(Of TextBox)`. I wouldn't necessarily say that this is superior in this specific case but it's good to know about such options. As far as readability is concerned, I think that that depends on your familiarity with LINQ. I tend to find this sort of thing more readable. There is an overhead but it's miniscule.

Comment: "Any" is an extension method for IEnumerable.  yes its static but you still have to create all the internals for it to work.  As of 3.5 the Array class implements IEnumerable.  Thats a lot of internal setup just to check something.  If this was a large list of items then i would agree but this is only a few textboxes so i think it overkill.