# DataGridView Row Filter not applying

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a DataGridView1 and I'm trying to filter it using a Row Filter. I also have a string: SomethingHere

I have a FilterString that I'm using as a string in the following format:

```
 Dim DGVDV As New DataView
 Using iConn As New OleDbConnection(ConnString)
      Using iDA As New OleDbDataAdapter(iSelectString, Conn)
           iDA.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
           iDA.FillSchema(DS.Tables("Table"), SchemaType.Source)
           iDA.Fill(DS.Tables("Table"))
           iBS.DataSource = DS.Tables("Table")
           DGVDV = DS.Tables("Table").DefaultView

           With DataGridView1
                .DataSource = iBS
           End With
      End Using
 End Using





 DGVDV = DS.Tables("Table").DefaultView
 DGVDV.RowFilter = FilterString
```

To prove that it's working, I have right below it:

```
 Msgbox("Filter: " & DGVDV.RowFilter.ToString)
```

This messagebox only fires when the FilterString is in this format:

```
 FilterString = "[Status] = '" & SomethingHere & "'"
```

However, the Row Filter seems to be ignoring a string like the two below:

```
 FilterString = "([Status] = '" & CMBFilter & "')" & " AND ([ID] LIKE '%" & SomethingHere & "%' OR [Name] LIKE '%" & SomethingHere & "%')"

 FilterString = "([ID] LIKE '%" & TextFilter & "%' OR [Name] LIKE '%" & TextFilter & "%')"
```

I've tried Googling, and I just can't figure out what the issue is.

```
    If CMBBool = True And TextBool = False Then
        FilterString = "[Status] = '" & CMBFilter & "'"
    ElseIf CMBBool = False And TextBool = True Then 
        FilterString = "([ID] LIKE '%" & TextFilter & "%' OR [Name] LIKE '%" & TextFilter & "%')"
        MsgBox(FilterString)
    ElseIf CMBBool = True And TextBool = True Then
        FilterString = "([Status] = '" & CMBFilter & "')" & " AND ([ID] LIKE '%" & TextFilter & "%' OR [Name] LIKE '%" & TextFilter & "%')"
        MsgBox(FilterString)
    ElseIf CMBBool = False And TextBool = False Then
        FilterString = String.Empty
    End If
    DGVDV.RowFilter = FilterString
    MsgBox("Filter: " & DGVDV.RowFilter.ToString)
```

When the FilterString is as below

```
 FilterString = "[Status] = '" & CMBFilter & "'"
```

The Msgbox pops up. For the other FilterStrings, no Msgbox pops up, making me suspect that the FilterString is never being applied to the row filter.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You don't need to suspect or use `MsgBox`.  You need to debug.  If you don't know how, now is the time to learn.  You need to set a breakpoint and then step through the code line by line, examining the state at each step.  Then you can see exactly what path execution takes and exactly what data was in use at every stage.

Comment: In addition to jmclhinney's comment, you'll want to be careful with your use of `And`. If you're wanting to do a strict `Boolean` comparison, the operator to use will be `AndAlso`. `And` is a [bitwise operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27111323/722393), which may give you unexpected results if you're expecting it to behave like `AndAlso`.

Comment: Thanks guys - I just debugged and set a breakpoint. As I suspected, when I'm using the longer FilterStrings, the DGDV.RowFilter is empty. Not sure why. Also, I've changed my operators to be AndAlso :).

Comment: AndAlso and OrElse are very handy because they short-circuit the evalution of the second condition. For the AndAlso if the first condition is False the second condition will not be evaluated. Often you might check a property of an object that is Nothing. Checking for Nothing first AndAlso checking for property will not cause the dreaded NRE. OrElse quites as soon as it finds a True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this format works:

```
DataView.RowFilter = string.Concat("CONVERT(", COLUMNNAME,",System.String) LIKE '%", TEXTBOXorSTRING, "%'")
```