# Problem when Minimize and maximize the program from the taskbar icon

Tags: vb.net

I had a problem when Minimize and maximize the program from the taskbar icon .
Where is the form without Border?
When I put the code to Minimize and maximize the program from the taskbar icon , it works without problems.
When I put the form extension code in all direction with Minimize and maximize code, the form extension code does not work, but only Minimize and maximize works.

Extension code: I mean increasing the width and height of the form by dragging the mouse from the edge inward or outward.

```
'Minimize and maximize the program from the taskbar icon form 
   Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams As CreateParams
        Get
            Dim CPa As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
            CPa.Style = CPa.Style Or &HA0000

            Return (CPa)
        End Get
    End Property
```

```
'form extension

 Private Const WM_NCHITTEST As Integer = &H84
    Private Const WM_MOUSEMOVE As Integer = &H200
    Private Const WM_LBUTTONDOWN As Integer = &H201
    'Private Const WM_LBUTTONUP As Integer = &H202
    Private Const MK_LBUTTON As Integer = &H1
    Private Const HTLEFT As Integer = &HA
    Private Const HTRIGHT As Integer = &HB
    Private Const HTTOP As Integer = &HC
    Private Const HTTOPLEFT As Integer = &HD
    Private Const HTTOPRIGHT As Integer = &HE
    Private Const HTBOTTOM As Integer = &HF
    Private Const HTBOTTOMLEFT As Integer = &H10
    Private Const HTBOTTOMRIGHT As Integer = &H11
    Private OffSet As Point = Point.Empty


    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        If m.Msg = WM_NCHITTEST Then
            Dim loc As New Point(m.LParam.ToInt32 And &HFFFF, m.LParam.ToInt32 >> 16)
            loc = PointToClient(loc)
            Dim bTop As Boolean = (loc.Y < ClientRectangle.Y + 4)
            Dim bLeft As Boolean = (loc.X < ClientRectangle.X + 4)
            Dim bRight As Boolean = (loc.X > Width - 4)
            Dim bBottom As Boolean = (loc.Y > Height - 4)
            If bTop AndAlso bLeft Then
                m.Result = CType(HTTOPLEFT, IntPtr)
                Return
            ElseIf bTop AndAlso bRight Then
                m.Result = CType(HTTOPRIGHT, IntPtr)
                Return
            ElseIf bBottom AndAlso bLeft Then
                m.Result = CType(HTBOTTOMLEFT, IntPtr)
                Return
            ElseIf bBottom AndAlso bRight Then
                m.Result = CType(HTBOTTOMRIGHT, IntPtr)
                Return
            ElseIf bLeft Then
                m.Result = CType(HTLEFT, IntPtr)
                Return
            ElseIf bTop Then
                m.Result = CType(HTTOP, IntPtr)
                Return
            ElseIf bRight Then
                m.Result = CType(HTRIGHT, IntPtr)
                Return
            ElseIf bBottom Then
                m.Result = CType(HTBOTTOM, IntPtr)
                Return
            End If
        ElseIf m.Msg = WM_LBUTTONDOWN Then
            OffSet = New Point(MousePosition.X - Me.Location.X, MousePosition.Y - Me.Location.Y)
        ElseIf m.Msg = WM_MOUSEMOVE AndAlso m.WParam.ToInt32 = MK_LBUTTON Then
            Me.Location = New Point(MousePosition.X - OffSet.X, MousePosition.Y - OffSet.Y)
        End If
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Fix1: `CPa.Style = CPa.Style Or &HA0000`. Fix2: Use `AndAlso` in `If` statements instead of `And`.

Comment: hi dr.null  what  means Fix2: Use AndAlso in If statements instead of And. –????

Comment: Ex, `If bTop AndAlso bLeft Then ...` instead of `If bTop And bLeft Then ...`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302047/what-is-the-difference-between-and-and-andalso-in-vb-net) for more.

Comment: I changed but nothing new happened

Comment: Replace `&HA0000` (WS_SYSMENU Or WS_MINIMIZEBOX) with `&H20000` (WS_MINIMIZEBOX). The `WS_SYSMENU` is the problem here and you don't need it. See [Window Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles).