# (OrElse and Or) and (AndAlso and And) - When to use?

Tags: vb.net, syntax, operators

What is the difference between (OrElse and Or) and (AndAlso and And)?
Is there any difference in their performances, let say the correctness benefit?? Is there any situation that I shoudn't use OrElse and AndAlso?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I always use the AndAlso and OrElse operators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55013/should-i-always-use-the-andalso-and-orelse-operators)

Comment: Just started using VB.NET (first time in many years for VB).  I came online only to ask this specific question. My thanks to @aer and the many folks who clarified with their great answers.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`Or/And` will *always* evaluate *both*<sup>1</sup> the expressions and then return a result. They are *not* short-circuiting.

`OrElse/AndAlso` are [short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). The right expression is only evaluated if the outcome cannot be determined from the evaluation of the left expression alone. (That means: `OrElse` will only evaluate the right expression if the left expression is false, and `AndAlso` will only evaluate the right expression if the left expression is true.)

Assuming that *no side effects* occur in the expressions and the expressions *are not dependent* (and any execution overhead is ignored), then they are the same.

However, in many cases it is that the expressions *are* dependent. For instance, we want to do something when a List is not-Nothing and has more than one element:

```
If list IsNot Nothing AndAlso list.Length > 0 Then .. 'list has stuff
```

This can also be used to avoid an "expensive" computation (or side-effects, ick!):

```
If Not Validate(x) OrElse Not ExpensiveValidate(x) Then .. 'not valid
```

Personally, I find that `AndAlso` and `OrElse` are the *correct* operators to use in all but the 1% - or less, hopefully! - of the cases where a side-effect *is* desired.

Happy coding.

---

<sup>1</sup> An Exception thrown in the first expression will prevent the second expression from being evaluated, but this should hardly be surprising ..

Answer (score 10):

Besides the short-circuiting mentioned in the other answers, `Or`/`And` are usable as bitwise operators where `OrElse`/`AndAlso` are not.  Bitwise operations include combining values of Flags enums, such as the [FileAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes.aspx) enumeration where you might indicate a file is both read only and hidden by `FileAttributes.ReadOnly Or FileAttributes.Hidden`

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that OrElse and AndAlso will short-circuit based on the first condition, meaning that if the first condition doesn't pass, the second (or more) conditions will not be evaluated. This is particularly useful when one of the conditions might be more intensive than the other.

Example where `Or` is fine (both conditions evaluated):

```
If Name = "Fred" Or Name = "Sam" Then
```

It really doesn't matter which way around they are evaluated

The following `AndAlso` is useful because the second condition might fail

```
If Not SomeObject Is Nothing AndAlso CheckObjectExistsInDatabase(SomeObject) Then
```

This allows for the first condition to check whether the object has been set and only if it has been set will go and check the database (or some other task). If this had been a plain `And` keyword, both would be evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

@Gideon - glad someone pointed that out. Here is a simple test that shows the dramatic impact of AndAlso:

```
    Dim tm As New Stopwatch
    Const tries As Integer = 123456
    Dim z As Integer = 0
    Dim s() As String = New String() {"0", "one"}

    Debug.WriteLine("AndAlso")
    For x As Integer = 0 To s.Length - 1
        z = 0
        tm.Restart() 'restart the stopwatch
        For y As Integer = 0 To tries
            If s(x) = x.ToString AndAlso s(x) = y.ToString Then '<<<<<<<<<<
                z += 1
            End If
        Next
        tm.Stop()
        Debug.WriteLine(x.ToString.PadRight(3, " "c) & z.ToString.PadRight(10, " "c) & tm.Elapsed.ToString)
    Next

    Debug.WriteLine("And")
    For x As Integer = 0 To s.Length - 1
        z = 0
        tm.Restart() 'restart the stopwatch
        For y As Integer = 0 To tries
            If s(x) = x.ToString And s(x) = y.ToString Then '<<<<<<<<<<
                z += 1
            End If
        Next
        tm.Stop()
        Debug.WriteLine(x.ToString.PadRight(3, " "c) & z.ToString.PadRight(10, " "c) & tm.Elapsed.ToString)
    Next
```