# Creating loops on VB.net window forms

Tags: vb.net

I just start learning programming and started with **VB.net** 5 days ago. I started with window forms on visual studio, I was given an assignment to insert a **loop** method on my mathematics calculations practice to make the program runs until I exit instead of running once. Thanks in advance and note I'm a **beginner,** don't use console practice or other, use **windows form**

Comment: there are plenty of tutorials on YouTube in regards to loops, you should start by going there, have a look, writing some code, and then if it fails, post your code within your question and we can help you, with that being said you want to look for the While Loop" as some people call it, it will look something like for example 'While True 'do something' End While'

Comment: You are also a **newcomer to this site** so you **should read** [Ask] and also take the [Tour] **before** you post again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you finde how to use the while statement in vb.net :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/zh1f56zs.aspx

```
Dim index As Integer = 0
While index < 100000
index += 1

' If index is between 5 and 7, continue
' with the next iteration.
If index >= 5 And index <= 8 Then
    Continue While
End If

' Display the index.
Debug.Write(index.ToString & " ")

' If index is 10, exit the loop.
If index = 10 Then
    Exit While
End If
End While

Debug.WriteLine("")
' Output: 1 2 3 4 9 10
```

Comment: Use [**`AndAlso`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb8x3kfz.aspx) instead, it performs [**short-circuiting**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409467/orelse-and-or-and-andalso-and-and-when-to-use).