# Snap PictureBox to Buttons after Drag and Drop

Tags: vb.net, drag-and-drop, alignment, snapping

I'm making a Battleship game, and I'm using buttons as the grid(playerboard). I'm using a picture box as the ship, and I'm trying to make it so that the picturebox snaps to the buttons that it is colliding with.

I have already done the drag and drop, and collision part, but I'm struggling with the snapping to buttons part. The picture box is the size of two buttons. I tried to align the picturebox with the buttons, by using picturebox.left = button.left, but it chooses the wrong button of the two.

```
Dim Off As Point
Private Sub picDestroyer_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles picDestroyer.MouseDown
    Off.X = MousePosition.X - sender.Left 'Click and Drag ship
    Off.Y = MousePosition.Y - sender.Top
End Sub

Private Sub picDestroyer_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles picDestroyer.MouseMove
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        sender.Left = MousePosition.X - Off.X 'Click and Drag ship
        sender.Top = MousePosition.Y - Off.Y
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub picDestroyer_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles picDestroyer.DoubleClick
    If picDestroyer.Size = New Size(52, 21) Then 'Rotate Pic if double clicked
        picDestroyer.Size = New Size(21, 52)
    ElseIf picDestroyer.Size = New Size(21, 52) Then
        picDestroyer.Size = New Size(52, 21)
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub picDestroyer_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles picDestroyer.MouseLeave

    For Each button In Me.Controls
        If picDestroyer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(button.bounds) Then
            button.backcolor = Color.Red
            picDestroyer.BackColor = SystemColors.Control
        End If
        If picDestroyer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(button.bounds) And picDestroyer.Size = New Size(52, 21) Then
            picDestroyer.Top = button.top
        End If
        If picDestroyer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(button.bounds) And picDestroyer.Size = New Size(21, 52) Then
            picDestroyer.Left = button.left
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the button which you want to snap to you can temporarily disable the `PictureBox` and call [**`GetChildAtPoint()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158404(v=vs.110).aspx) on the form to get the child control at the location of the `PictureBox`, specifying [**`GetChildAtPointSkip.Disabled`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.getchildatpointskip(v=vs.110).aspx) as the second parameter so that the search won't include your disabled `PictureBox` but all the other controls above/below it.

After that you can just set the `PictureBox`'s coordinates to that of the button.

There are also a few improvements that can be made to your code:

- You can use the [**`MouseUp` event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseup(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `MouseLeave` to update the picture box's position immediately after you drop it.
- Set both the X- and Y-coordinates for the picture box when snapping (not just one of them, `Left = X, Top = Y`) so that it is snapped correctly in the top-left corner of the button.
- In the loop iterate through `Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)()` instead of just `Me.Controls`, since [**`OfType(Of TResult)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) will get **only** the controls of a certain type (in this case `Button`s). Iterating through only `Me.Controls` will for example include the `PictureBox` itself which could cause issues in the future (perhaps that was the reason you set its `BackColor` to `Control` every time?).

All that said, this code should work:

```
If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then

    picDestroyer.Enabled = False 'Temporarily disable the picture box so that it isn't included in the child search.
    Dim ChildBelowDestroyer As Control = Me.GetChildAtPoint(picDestroyer.Location, GetChildAtPointSkip.Disabled) 'Look for any child control that isn't disabled.
    picDestroyer.Enabled = True 'Re-enable the picture box.

    If ChildBelowDestroyer Is Nothing OrElse _
        ChildBelowDestroyer.GetType() IsNot GetType(Button) Then
        Return 'Do not continue if no child was found below the picture box, or if the child is not a button.
    End If

    picDestroyer.Location = ChildBelowDestroyer.Location 'Snap the picture box to the button (sets the X- and Y-coordinates).

    For Each button In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)() 'OfType() to only look for buttons.
        If picDestroyer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(button.Bounds) Then
            button.BackColor = Color.Red
            picDestroyer.BackColor = SystemColors.Control
        End If
    Next

End If
```

Another thing to keep in mind is to use [**`AndAlso`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb8x3kfz.aspx) instead of `And`, and [**`OrElse`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea1sssb2.aspx) instead of `Or` in `If`-statements since `AndAlso` and `OrElse` are [**short-circuited**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8409467/3740093).

Comment: After adding the Exit For into the if statement, the button backcolor nolonger changes to red. Also the picDestroyer.top = button.top and picDestroyer.Left = button.left no longer works. I also combined the if statements, and my code looks identical to what you provided. I appreciate the help

Comment: @Erika : Hmm, that's strange... I'll have to try the code out then.

Comment: @Erika : I have updated the entire answer with new code and some explanations. Hope it'll be what you need!

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! When I tried `If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then`, `e.button` was underlined saying "e.button is not a member of "system.eventargs". I got rid of the if statement completely, and it still seemed to work. Thank you for the help, I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: @Erika : Glad I could help! -- For `e.Button` to work you must have a proper event declaration. The best way to get one is to remove any existing handlers and then select the event from the event box in Visual Studio. A proper declaration for `MouseUp` would be: `Private Sub picDestroyer_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles picDestroyer.MouseUp` - note the _"e As **MouseEventArgs**"_.