# Translate C# into VB

Tags: c#, vb.net

**Problem:**

I currently have the following line of code in C#:

```
if ((oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("LetterTo_name") == (oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("firstname") + " " + oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("lastname"))) && (oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("Name")).Contains("OMEGA") || (oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("Name")).Contains("Alpha"))
```

and it displays what I want correctly.

However, when I try to do the same thing but in VB:

```
IF ((oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("LetterTo_name") = (oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("firstname") + " " + oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("lastname"))) And ((oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("Name")).Contains("Omega") Or (oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("Name")).Contains("Alpha"))) THEN
```

It displays no results. Meaning when I run my C# version of the code, it displays an image but for the VB version, nothing occurs.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Hello Everyone. I would like to thank you all for your help and helping me get a better understanding with VB. However, it is still not displaying any images and I am not sure why.

The following is what I am doing. For some reason, when I try to assigned variables, it did not display any results as well. Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<table width="100%" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0">
<tr>
 <td align="center">
 <%
 IF ((oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("LetterTo_name") = (oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("firstname") & " " & oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("lastname"))) AndAlso ((oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("Name")).Contains("OMEGA") OrElse (oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("Name")).Contains("ALPHA"))) THEN
  select (oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("Site")) 
   case "R107":
   case "R0712":
   case "R108":
   case "R10812":
   case "R113":
   case "R11312":
   case "R115":
   case "R11512":
   case "R10702":
   case "R10802":
   case "R11302":
   case "R11502":
   case "RG112":
    Response.Write("<img src='/images/logos/COLA-m.jpg'>")
   case "RG109":
   case "RG10912":
   case "RG110":
   case "RG11012":
   case "RG10902":
   case "RG11002":
    Response.Write("<img src='/images/logos/regalcodow-m.jpg'>")
      End select
ELSEIF (oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("Name") = (oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("firstname") & " " & oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("lastname"))) THEN
   case "RG112":
   case "RG11212":
   case "RG11202":
    Response.Write("<img src='/images/logos/RegalBG-m.jpg'>")    
   case "RMG117":
   case "RMG11712":
   case "RMG11702":
    Response.Write("<img src='/images/logos/RegalGle-m.jpg'>")    
   case "MG101":
   case "MG10112":
   case "MG102":
   case "G10212":
   case "G116":
   case "G11612":
   case "118":
   case "11812":
   case "10102":
   case "G10202":
   case "G11602":
   case "G11802":
    Response.Write("<img src='/images/logos/RegalSFV-m.jpg'>")
     End select
Else
  IF((oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("Facility") <> (oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("firstname") & " " & oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("lastname"))) OrElse (oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("_ReferredTo") <> (oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("firstname") & " " & oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("lastname"))) OrElse (oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("ReferredFrom") <> (oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("firstname") & " " & oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("lastname"))) OrElse (oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("pcpname") <> (oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("firstname") & " " & oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("lastname")))) THEN
select (oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("PatientSite")) 
    case "MG112":
    case "MG11212":
    case "MG11202":
     Response.Write("<img src='/images/logos/RegalBG.bmp'>")    
    case "MG117":
    case "MG11712":
    case "MG11702":
     Response.Write("<img src='/images/logos/RegalGle.bmp'>")     
    case "MG101":
    case "MG10112":
    case "MG102":
    case "MG10212":
    case "RG116":
    case "MG11612":
    case "MG118":
    case "MG11812":
    case "MG10102":
    case "MG10202":
    case "MG11602":
    case "MG11802":
     Response.Write("<img src='/images/logos/RegalSFV.bmp'>")
     End select
  End If
End If
 %>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Just for your sanity, consider breaking that into multiple statements (that prepare the strings, call some of the methods, etc)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: K Thanks

Comment: Erik has isolated the main problem, but you should be aware that "And" is not the equivalent of C#'s "&&" operator and "Or" is not the equivalent of C#'s "||" operator - you want the VB logical operators "AndAlso" and "OrElse".

Comment: @DaveDoknjas: I have tried everyones recommendation and yet I still displaying a blank page. I will shortly post what I did

Comment: If you expect a match in Case "R107" through Case "RG112" to execute the code for "RG112", then write it as `Case "R107", "R0712", ... all other matches..., "RG112"` on a single line and not as separate cases.

Comment: @TnTinMn: I have tried that and it still does not render any results

Answer (score 7):

A good debugging strategy in a situation like this is to take your evaluations outside your if statement and use the debugger to step through and make sure the values are getting calculated correctly.

**C#**

```
var letterToName = oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("LetterTo_name");
var fullName = oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("firstname") + " " + oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("lastname");
var containsOmega = oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("Name").Contains("OMEGA");
var containsAlpha = oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("Name").Contains("Alpha");

if ((letterToName == fullName) && containsOmega || containsAlpha)
```

**VB**

```
dim letterToName = oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("LetterTo_name")
dim fullName = oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("firstname") + " " + oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("lastname")
dim containsOmega = oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("Name").Contains("Omega")
dim containsAlpha = oAEAuthInfo.GetInfo("Name").Contains("Alpha")

IF ((letterToName = fullName) And (containsOmega Or containsAlpha)) THEN
```

And it becomes clear what your problem is: you have an extra set of parenthesis in the VB code that are missing from the C# code. Order of operations dictate that `and` operators take precedence over `or` operators, so in the C# code if `containsAlpha` is true the condition always passes, whereas in the VB code that will only happen if `letterToName = fullName` is also true.

Also, case sensitivity of `"Omega"` may be the problem.

As Visual Vincent pointed out, the `And` and `Or` operators do not actually correspond to the behavior of C#'s `&&` and `||` operators - instead VB's operators that are equivalent would be `AndAlso` and `OrElse`. That is unlikely to be the source of the problem in this situation unless `GetInfo` or `Contains` have some side-effects.

Comment: beat me only by seconds :)

Comment: Also why its a good idea to have multiple statements instead of one giant `if` :)

Comment: Instead of `Or` and `And` you should use [**`OrElse` and `AndAlso`**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8409488/3740093), and [**`&` is preferred over `+` for concatenations**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/734631/3740093).

Comment: @VisualVincent Good call out - OrElse and AndAlso are a better match for the behavior of C#'s operators.

Comment: I do not know if it is applicable to this instance, but in general one should be careful using VB's equality operator for strings to yield a boolean value.  The backward compatibility requirement that VB.Net adheres to can lead to some confusing issues.  First you have `Option Compare  = Text/Binary`.  Secondly, the equality operator for strings treats Nothing (null) as String.Empty; so the result of: `Nothing=String.Empty` will be True.  It is safer to use one of the various equality functions available on the String type. i.e: `string1.Equals(string2)` or `String.Equals(string1, string2)`