# VB.net Logic is not giving expected output

Tags: vb.net

When I add this code in my project then the logic is not giving expected output

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter And cbmPassportCountry.Text.Trim() <> "" Then
    SendKeys.Send("{tab}")
Else
    If btnSave.Enabled = True Then
        btnSave.Focus()
    End If
End If
```

If I use this logic then my code gives expected output

```
Private Sub cbmPassportCountry_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles cbmPassportCountry.KeyDown
    'If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter And cbmPassportCountry.Text.Trim() <> "" Then
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        If btnSave.Enabled = True Then
            btnSave.Focus()
        Else
            SendKeys.Send("{tab}")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

But I want to implement that `And` Logic in my code which will work like my next logic

Comment: you say it doesn't work what does that mean?

Comment: @Mederic When i add that logic instead of nested if logic then my code is not working. But when Comment out my AND logic and use nested logic then this code works fine

Comment: you still didn't understand: doesn't work means nothing! **do you get an error? or a warning? or is the code not executed?**

Comment: @Mederic My code is running but i am not getting the expected output such as i want to enable the tab if the condition meets otherwise the else condition will work.

Comment: Could you please explain how you want this to work/what result you're expecting? Currently it is not clear what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your problem. Did you try to use 'AndAlso' instead of 'And'? If this doesn't work, split it into two If-commands.

Comment: @VisualVincent I want my And logic work like my second logic. Basically i want to know why my AND logic is not working Because i don't want to use multiple if logics in my code

Comment: @muffi : In this case `AndAlso` won't make a difference. It will only skip evaluating the right side if the left is `False`. Even if both sides are evaluated by `And`, if the left is `False` it won't continue anyway so the outcome of both will be the same.

Comment: @muffi I haven't used AndAlso in my code but when i split my code into multiple if conditions then my code works fine. But that adds a lots of line to my project

Comment: @Visual Vincent if `AndAlso` makes no difference in this case, why is your answer exactly this and Tazbirul's code is working?

Comment: @muffi : Because I'm using nested `If`s. The reason I use `AndAlso` is because I always use that in my `If`-statements.

Comment: @Visual Vincent I don't catch so far why your answer is correct and my answer not - both using `AndAlso`.

Comment: @muffi : Because switching to `AndAlso` in his initial code doesn't make a difference. Using nested `If`s is the solution. I could've used `And` in my code as well, but that would've been unnecessary.

Comment: @muffi : The only reason I used `AndAlso` is because I consider it bad practice to use `And`. It only affects speed in this case, not the outcome.

Comment: @Visual Vincent 100% agree to your last comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your first block to work like the second, but checking that `cbmPassportCountry.Text` isn't empty, why don't you just add that to your second statement?

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter AndAlso cbmPassportCountry.Text.Trim() <> "" Then
    If btnSave.Enabled = True Then
        btnSave.Focus()
    Else
        SendKeys.Send("{tab}")
    End If
End If
```

You cannot put this in one `If`-statement ***without*** having to make additional, unnecessary checks.

Comment: Yap. now i am getting the expected output. Thanks a lot for your help. I was totally unaware about this AndAlso keyword. I was using And in my logic and that was not giving the expecte doutput but AndAlso is worrking fine

Comment: @TazbirulHaque : `AndAlso` doesn't make a difference in this case. It is better to use it, which is why I switched to it, but it doesn't affect the outcome. What changed is that you **must** use nested `If`s, otherwise you'd have to check `e.KeyCode` **twice** which is completely unnecessary.

Comment: I am new in vb.net that's why i am not familiar with this logics.Thanks again for your cordial help.

Comment: @TazbirulHaque : No problem. I didn't have the time to post the link earlier, see this for more info on the difference between `AndAlso` and `And`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409467/orelse-and-or-and-andalso-and-and-when-to-use

Comment: You are really awesome. I am really grateful to you. I hope that you will lead me in future with your awesome solutions.But i don't know is it possible to follow you or any other way to communicate with you. If there is any possible way then please let me know!! Thank you once again.