# What's the equivalent of AndAlso (&&) and OrElse (||) logical operators in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, logical-operators, equivalent

In .NET VB and C#, we can use AndAlso (**&&**), OrElse (**||**) for logical operations

How about in Python, what is the equivalent logical operators? are they only limited to '**and**' and '**or**'?

**Updated**: Below is the difference between And/Or and AndAlso/OrElse
Quoted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/8409488/719998

> Or/And will always evaluate both1 the expressions and then return a
>   result. They are not [short-circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) evaulation.
>
> OrElse/AndAlso are short-circuiting. The right expression is only evaluated if the outcome cannot be determined from the evaluation
>   of the left expression alone. (That means: OrElse will only evaluate
>   the right expression if the left expression is false, and AndAlso will
>   only evaluate the right expression if the left expression is true.)

Comment: What is the logical difference between `and` and `AndAlso`? I don't know VB/C#, so there *might* be a difference, but I can't imagine what. If you need Python people to answer, you should clarify the expected behaviour.

Comment: Please check this tutorial with your answers: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm
Regards,

Comment: There are **"or"**, **"and"** and **"not"** Source : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/logical_operators_example.htm

Comment: Poking around a bit, it sounds like VB's `AndAlso` is short circuiting while `And` is not. Python's `and` is short circuiting. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python already does this:

```
def foo():
    print ("foo")
    return True

def bar():
    print ("bar")
    return False


print (foo() or bar())
print ("")
print (bar() or foo())
```

Returns:

```
foo
True

bar
foo
True
```

There is no need for AndAlso or OrElse in Python, it evaluates boolean conditions lazily ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations)).

Answer (score 0):

In python, you can use **logic gates**.

You can use either, for instance, `and` or `&`.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types