# How to allow backspace and space when validating letters?

Tags: .net, vb.net, validation, backspace

The code I am using is this:

```
If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 65 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) < 90 _
And Asc(e.KeyChar) < 97 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 122 Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter letters only")
    e.Handled = True
End If
```

How to allow backspace and space when validating letters in VB?

Comment: Are you sure this is correct: `Or Asc(e.KeyChar) < 90`? Didn't you mean to check if it was _**greater**_ than 90?

Comment: Yes, a key element of any good UI is to scold and punish the user for every erroneous keystroke.  No typos allowed.

Answer (score 3):

Character code for backspace is 8 and for space is 32, so your code should be:

```
If (Asc(e.KeyChar) < 65 OrElse Asc(e.KeyChar) < 90) _
AndAlso (Asc(e.KeyChar) < 97 OrElse Asc(e.KeyChar) > 122) _
AndAlso Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 AndAlso Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 32 Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter letters only")
    e.Handled = True
End If
```

Note that I used `AndAlso`, to stop the evaluation when the first `False` is encountered.

Comment: Since you switched to `AndAlso` you might want to use [**`OrElse`**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8409467) as well ;). Also, consider grouping the `Or/OrElse` checks with brackets. That way it is easier to read, but you also ensure that it executes correctly.