# Conversion from string "word" to type 'Boolean' is not valid

Tags: vb.net

```
Do While Alien(0).Text = Alien(1).Text Or Alien(2).Text Or Alien(3).Text Or Alien(4).Text Or Alien(5).Text
     rand()
     Alien(0).Text = WordBank(Word)
Loop
```

rand() chooses a random word inside an array and assigns the random word to the Word variable

Comment: Thats not the correct way to use logical `Or`.  I invite you to study the [Logical and Bitwise Operators Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/operators-and-expressions/logical-and-bitwise-operators).  Also read [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot compare strings like that. You've got to re-check `Alien(0).Text` for every `Or`, otherwise it tries to evaluate your strings as `Boolean` values (True or False).

This is why you get the error: a string (other than `"True"` or `"False"`) cannot be converted into a `Boolean`, because, how would the compiler know how to convert for instance `"Bear"` into either `True` or `False`?

Also, it is much better to use `OrElse` since it is [short-circuited](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8409467), meaning if one check succeeds it won't bother checking the rest of them.

```
Do While Alien(0).Text = Alien(1).Text OrElse Alien(0).Text = Alien(2).Text OrElse Alien(0).Text = Alien(3).Text OrElse Alien(0).Text = Alien(4).Text OrElse Alien(0).Text = Alien(5).Text
```

Comment: WOW thank you very much.
this has solved the problem without any other errors.
Thank you so very much!