# How to give a "ctrl + " shortcut key for a button in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, button, shortcut

how to add a " ctrl + " shortcut to button in vb.net. For example I need to perform click event of save button when ctrl + s is pressed.

Comment: WinForms or WPF? - Either way, buttons tend to have an `Alt-S` shortcut assigned and menu options have the `Ctrl-S` action. I think this is just the way Windows Apps have developed over the years

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Winforms Solution**

In your Form class, set its `KeyPreview` property to true, example of it being set in the Form constructor, either set it here or via the Designer:

```
Public Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Me.KeyPreview = True
End Sub
```

Then all you need to do is handle the `KeyDown` event for the Form, like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If (e.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.S) Then
        Debug.Print("Call Save action here")
    End If
End Sub
```

**WPF Solution (Not using MVVM pattern)**

Add this to your .xaml file

```
<Window.Resources>
    <RoutedUICommand x:Key="SaveCommand" Text="Save" />
</Window.Resources>

<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource SaveCommand}" Executed="SaveAction" />
</Window.CommandBindings>

<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="S" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="{StaticResource SaveCommand}" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

Alter your button definition to include `Command="{StaticResource SaveCommand}"`, for example:

```
<Button x:Name="Button1" Content="Save" Command="{StaticResource SaveCommand}" />
```

In your Code Behind (.xaml.vb) put your function to call the save routine, such as:

```
Private Sub SaveAction(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Debug.Print("Call Save action here")
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice answer! Though please see [the difference between And and AndAlso](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8409467/3740093).

Comment: @VisualVincent Thanks for the tip. Normally I spend my time in C# and the `AndAlso` keyword totally slipped my mind. I edited to use `AndAlso`

Comment: @cody196 That good to hear. Don't forget to Accept it as the answer to help other people looking for a similar solution

Comment: @ visual vincent: Yeah sure!