# Checking whether value is DBNull

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following function:

```
Public Shared Function imageExists(ByVal path As Object) As Boolean
                If IsDBNull(path) = False Or Not path Is Nothing Then
                    Dim pathString As String = Convert.ToString(path)
                    If Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path)) Then
                        Return True
                    Else
                        Return False
                    End If
                Else
                    Return False
                End If

            End Function
```

Called by the visible property for this image control:

```
<asp:Image ID="img_SmallImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "~/Content/Images/Exclusive/" + Eval("trip_SmallImage") %>' Visible='<%# OnTheMain.Images.Validation.imageExists(Eval("trip_SmallImage"))%>' />
```

No matter what I try for the `If IsDBNull` part, it either ignores it and executes the code, or returns an error such as `Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid.`

How can I rectify the situation?

Comment: Sorry, the 'or not nothing' was a mistake when I copied the code into the question. Unfortunately none of these answers worked. I tried changing the object to string, but to no avail. Is there anything else I can try? I just constantly get this error 'Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid.'

Comment: BTW, I am answering you to handle the exception, that not means that your question is logical, please edit your question first,

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're trying to say. I have corrected the mistake if that's what you meant. The exception handling doesn't work I'm afraid, as I said, I've tried all three answers on this question.

Answer (score 2):

you have a logical error in the first if check.

`Not Nothing` always evaluates to true. so that first statement basically compiles down to:

```
If IsDBNull(path) Or True Then
```

which will always be true. your if statement should probably look like this:

```
If Not IsDBNull(path) And path Is Not Nothing Then
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are using both `IsDBNull` and `Nothing`, anyway

Use [AndAlso](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb8x3kfz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), it will not check the next part if previous is false

check the path first to prevent the exception:

```
        If path IsNot Nothing AndAlso IsDBNull(path) = False Then
        'do what ever you want to do
    End If
```

FYI,  [OrElse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea1sssb2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  will do the same function for `Or`, for me i am using this short-circuiting logical operators by default read my question on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782516/why-andalso-is-not-a-replacement-to-and)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(path) Then
```

as you need to handle empty strings. You should be passing a String, not a generic Object.  Also, you can't do `Or Not Nothing`.  You would have to do `Not IsDBNull(path) And Not path Is Nothing`.